# Restore of elasticsearch snapshot not working using cloud-aws plugin and s3 regions

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to restore a snapshot from s3 using the elasticsearch cloud-aws plugin. Both elasticsearch and cloud-aws plugin are on version 2.2.0.

The weird thing is that on my local machine I can only restore the snapshot if I specify the region, like this:

```
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "bucketname",
    "region": "us-west-1",
    "access_key": "XXXX",
    "secret_key": "XXXX",
    "base_path": "path/to/snapshot",
    "compress": "true"
  }
}
```

If I leave out the region, the snapshot restore will fail with the following error (names have been changed of course):

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[repositoryname] path [path][to][snapshot] is not accessible on master node"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_verification_exception",
    "reason": "[repositoryname] path [path][to][snapshot] is not accessible on master node",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "i_o_exception",
      "reason": "Unable to upload object path/to/snapshot/tests-pJjA4cwNREu8RsFsXTn4Qg/master.dat-temp",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "amazon_s3_exception",
        "reason": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 7D8675025D7DB3ED)"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

However, on my server, the snapshot restore will only succeed if I **don't** specify the region, like this:

```
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "bucketname",
    "access_key": "XXXX",
    "secret_key": "XXXX",
    "base_path": "path/to/snapshot",
    "compress": "true"
  }
}
```

If I **do** specify the region, no matter which region I pick, then the snapshot restore will fail with the same error as shown above.

Since I am automating the snapshot restore, I want the behaviour to be predictable across all servers and localhost. What am I doing wrong? Or missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause myself: I did an update of my Java JRE/JDK, and also the JAVA_HOME environmental variable and the Elasticsearch windows service, but for some reason I still needed to do a restart of Windows to get the cloud-aws plugin working again.